# Unable to implement Crashlytics in android

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging, crashlytics

I have a project where fcm was already implemented. Now I have to implement Firebase Crashlytics in the same project. For adding crashlytics, I followed [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android) page. While syncing the project, I found some error:

> ERROR: In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[16.0.
> 5]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

After that I upgraded the version for fcm and issue was fixed.
But after that I got error:

> cannot find class FirebaseInstanceIdService

Since, now FirebaseInstanceIdService is deprecated in new fcm implementation, I get this error.

Then I remove the class where FirebaseInstanceIdService is extended. But, now I get error:

> cannot find symbol method injectMembers

I have implemented dagger in my project. And error is related to that but I haven't changed anything in dagger code. What do I do?

Comment: I believe Firebase Crashlytics has a transitive dependency on Dagger, I'm not sure if FCM does but it may as well. If you're implementing Dagger into your project yourself and running into issues with these dependencies and Dagger, it seems possible there's some version mismatching happening here. Could you try isolating the dependencies by commenting out your Dagger implementation and testing just Crashlytics+FCM? Pasting your Gradle file here would also help.

Answer (score 0):

Just upgrading Dagger to the latest version fixed the issue. You can find the updated version [over here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.google.dagger/dagger)